# Wordpress Mixed content requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint

Tags: wordpress, nginx, https, mixed-content

OK I checked all other similar answers, but thanks to people that downvote for no reason there is no actual response.

I am using Wordpress and I have a Mixed Content with a website https://oujdaportail.net/

It is generating this error:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://oujdaportail.net/' was loaded over
>   HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint
>   'http://oujdaportail.net/'. This request has been blocked; the content
>   must be served over HTTPS.

Chrome debug console has been completely useless!! It detects the error at the first line of source code where there is nothing to look up.

I am not sure how I should resolve this... I need help to capture the source of this issue.

Comment: If your questions are getting downvoted, then they do not meet the guidelines for the site. Please review the [help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) It is Stack Overflow policy to downvote questions that don't meet the site guidelines. We cannot help if you do not give enough information - we are not mind readers! We don't know your code or what is causing your error. You need to debug the issue yourself - Chrome debug console is not the start and end for debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally! I would be someone's hero...

After hours of struggle, it turned out that `wp_head` and `wp_footer` where responsible for generating unknown HTTP requests. And to fix it all I had to do is create a custom wp_head and wp_footer function just like this:

```
/**
 * Wrapper for wp_head() which manages SSL
 *
 * @uses    wp_head()
 * @param   bool    $ssl
 * @return  void
 */
function custom_wp_head() {
  // Capture wp_head output with buffering
  ob_start();
  wp_head();
  $wp_head = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();

  // Replace plain protocols
  $wp_head = preg_replace( '/(["\'])http:\/\//', '\1https://', $wp_head );

  // Output
  echo $wp_head;
}

function custom_wp_footer() {
  // Capture wp_head output with buffering
  ob_start();
  wp_footer();
  $wp_footer = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();

  // Replace plain protocols
  $wp_footer = preg_replace( '/(["\'])http:\/\//', '\1https://', $wp_footer );

  // Output
  echo $wp_footer;
}
```